# Possible wrong textbook answer, or did I misinterpret?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Context: this is a question from a textbook provided by my lecturer as practice. In the answer sheet, the answer is $0.22$, from my working, the answer is $0.27$. Since the lecturer has mentioned that some errors are present in the textbook I wanted to get a second opinion.

Question:

> Probability of event A, normal supply of water from source A, is $0.7$.
> Probability of event B, normal supply of water from source B, is $0.85$.
> Probability of source B having below-normal supply of water given that source A is below normal is $0.3$. 
> Find the probability that only one of the two water sources will be below normal supply.

My working:

> $P({\bar{B}}|{\bar{A}})$ = 0.3
> $P({\bar{B}}|{\bar{A}}) = P({\bar{B}}{\bar{A}}) ÷ P({\bar{A}})$
> $∴0.3 = P({\bar{B}}{\bar{A}}) ÷ (1 - 0.7)$
> $P({\bar{B}}{\bar{A}}) = 0.3 * 0.3 = 0.09$

> $P({\bar{B}}{\bar{A}}) + P(B) + P(A{\bar{B}}) = 1$
> $0.09 + 0.85 + P(A{\bar{B}}) = 1$
> $∴P(A{\bar{B}})=0.06$
> $P(AB) = P(A) - P(A{\bar{B}})$
> $= 0.7 - 0.06$
> $= 0.64$

> $P($only one of the two water sources will be below normal supply$)$ 
>  $= 1 - P[($normal supply from both sources$)∪($below normal supply from both sources$)]$
> $=1-P[(AB)∪({\bar{A}}{\bar{B}})]$
> Since $AB$ and ${\bar{A}}{\bar{B}}$ are mutually exclusive events,
> $=1-[P(AB)+P({\bar{A}}{\bar{B}})]$
> $=1-P(AB)-P({\bar{A}}{\bar{B}})$
> $=1-0.64-0.09$
> $= 0.27$

Did I make a logical fallacy or something that would lead to the difference between the given answer and my answer? No textbook solution provided.

Comment: At a glance, this all appears correct.

Comment: $P(\bar A, \bar B)=0.09$, $P(\bar A,  B)=0.21$, $P( A, \bar B)=0.06$, $P( A,  B)=0.64$ looks correct and $0.21+0.06=0.27$